# Express App - Creating a Nested Route with ES Modules

Tags: node.js, express, nested-routes, esmodules

I've followed a tutorial to create an Express app with an API. With the tutorial completed, I am now trying to convert it from CommonJS to ES Modules. I tried looking through resources like the Express documentation but they are mostly still written in CJS, which is understandable but not very helpful for me. After a lot of troubleshooting in my app.js file and learning a bit about how to use Webpack, I've gotten pretty far in the conversion process but the one error I can't figure out relates to nested routes.

**App Design Context:**

Two of the app's API collections are for tour data and tour review data. One page of the app displays a tour's details including user reviews. My API has reviews that use parent referencing to tours, so I have a review route nested inside my tour router: `router.use("/:tourId/reviews, reviewRouter)`.

Then in my review router, I have `mergeParams: true` so that when a request follows the route `/:tourId/reviews` and travels from the tour router to the review router, the review router code still has access to the request's `tourID` in order to retrieve parent-referenced data.

**Environment:**

Windows 11 OS
VS Code v1.83.1
Node v18.18.0

**Error Message:**

When I try to execute `npm run start` I get the following error in my IDE terminal:
.
OLD ERROR:

```
C:\[filePath]\[appName]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
            ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Module
    at Function.use (C:\[filePath]\[appName]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
    at file:///C:/[filePath]/[appName]/routes/tourRoutes.js:45:8
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

NEW ERROR in tourRoutes.js:

```
file:///C:/[filePath]/[appName]/routes/tourRoutes.js:45
router.use("/:tourId/reviews", reviewRouter);
                               ^

ReferenceError: reviewRouter is not defined
    at file:///C:/[filePath]/[appName]/routes/tourRoutes.js:45:32
```

**Relevant code - tourRoutes.js**

```
import express from "express";

import * as tourController from "../controllers/tourController.js";
import * as authController from "../controllers/authController.js";
import reviewRoutes from "./reviewRoutes.js";

const router = express.Router();

// =======================
// TOUR ROUTES

router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(tourController.getTour)
  .patch( // middleware )
  .delete( //middleware );

// =======================
// NESTED ROUTES

// LINE 45:
router.use("/:tourId/reviews", reviewRouter);

export default router;
```

**Relevant code - reviewRoutes.js**

```
import express from "express";

import * as reviewController from "../controllers/reviewController.js";
import * as authController from "../controllers/authController.js";

// Allows for nested route in tourRoutes.js:
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router
  .route("/")
  .get(reviewController.getAllReviews)
  .post(
    authController.restrictTo("user"),
    reviewController.setTourUserId,
    reviewController.createReview
  );

// Other routers with CRUD routes

export default router;
```

**Attempted Solutions**

I understand that the error is because I switched from CJS to ESM and my package.json file sets everything to modules, but when my code was using `const reviewRouter = require("./reviewRoutes")` CJS syntax, tourRoute.js' `router.use("/:tourId/reviews, reviewRouter)` code worked fine and `reviewRouter` was not a middleware function in and of itself - as far as I understand middleware.

If the solution is that I have to make my review router's `router.route("/")...` code a named function in order to export it, then I'm not sure how to do that correctly. I tried making the entire review router file code exportable with `export default reviewRouter` and then importing into the tour router as `import { reviewRouter} from "./reviewroutes.js"` but that did not work.

I also tried doing `export const nestedRoute = router.route("/")` couple with `export default router;` at the bottom of the review router, and then inside the tour router `import {nestedRoute} from "./reviewroutes.js` without success.

Comment: Have you exported your reviewRoutes.js as router?

Answer (score 0):

If you havent exported the reviewRoutes.js, please default export it as default

```
export default router
```

and on importing side dont import * as because that will import the whole module, where as we only want a middleware function so

```
import reviewRoutes from "./reviewRoutes.js";
```

Comment: Ack, when I deleted the various CRUD operations from my reviewRoute.js file I accidentally deleted `export default router` - I added that back into my post.

Changing to `import reviewRoutes from "./reviewRoutes.js"` in tourRoutes.js gives me a new error - so one step closer to solving this - now the error says that `reviewRouter` is not defined in Line 45 of tourRoutes.js.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how importing in ESM works. I understand that `import * as variable from "./module.js"` imports an entire module, and `import {name} from "./module.js"` imports a specific function/variable/middleware by that name. 

When I use `import reviewRoutes from "./reviewRoutes.js"` inside tourRoutes.js, to me that says tourRoutes.js should take all the code from reviewRoutes.js and assign it the variable name of 'reviewRoutes' so that I can reference it inside tourRoutes.js. But then what is the difference from `import * as ...`? I'm missing something.

Comment: Answering your import confusion/question: import reviewRoutes from "./reviewRoutes.js" will import your "default" export and import * as will import all exports.

Comment: can you update your latest tourRoutes.js in the question?

Comment: Ah! That answer makes a lot of sense, thank you! I've updated tourRoutes.js in the question now, and added in the new error message.

Comment: In tourRoutes.js, shouldn't I import it as `reviewRouter` instead of `reviewRoutes` since I have `router.use("/:tourId/reviews", reviewRouter);`? When I import as `reviewRouter` I no longer get the error message that it is undefined, I'm back to the error  message about "Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ` + gettype(fn))".

Comment: Yes, it should be router.use("/:tourId/reviews", reviewRoutes);
and created the same setup, its working for me.

Comment: Can you show me where you are importing your tourRoutes.js and how?